# What does 'function' object has no attribute 'tk' mean?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, attributes, python-3.5

I'm currently working on a program that lets you sign up to an account, and login again by writing the details to a txt document and reading them again, everything was working fine until I added this:

```
def login():
    fh = open("usernamepassword.txt", "r")
    lines = fh.readlines()
    fh.close()
    username=(lines[0])
    fname=(lines[2])
    lname=(lines[3])
```

This section isn't finished yet, but whenever I run the script without this in triple quotations, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robbie\Documents\Python\Signup - Login.py", line 274, in <module>
    b2=Button(login, text="Don't have an account? Make one here!", command=signupswitch)
  File "C:\Users\Robbie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2209, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Robbie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2132, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Robbie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2110, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

As you can see above, the variable 'b2' isn't related to the section above that what-so-ever. I've looked in tkinter's *init* file but, as I'm a beginner in python, there wasn't anything I could find there. I've searched for hours online for solutions to this problem, but I just can't find any! I really need this question answered as this goes toward my GCSE in computer science.

Comment: If your code crashes when you create a Button, you should probably read [the tkinter documentation about Buttons](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#reference). Instead of a few hours spent googling, all you need is 20 seconds to realize that the `login` function is not a valid `master` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are plugging the function `login` as the parent widget for your button :

```
b2=Button(login, text="Don't have an account? Make one here!", command=signupswitch)
```

Replace `login` with your root widget or whatever the parent widget is.